# How to remove IP Address and Email from Woocommerce Orders details admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am currently trying to remove the ip address from Woocommerce->Orders->Order Details. The method i have used for removing the emails and phone for the order details page was using the filter woocommerce_admin_billing_fields and then using unset to remove the variables. I figured this would be the same case for ip address but its not working, so im assuming i have to use a different filter?

In addition to this the emails displaying from Woocommerce -> Orders also dont
get remove, so is there a different filter for that as well?

Where can i find the filter for ip address and for email in woocommerce -> order? Or is there another method of removing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'update_post_metadata', 'mp1401091554', 10, 3 );

function mp1401091554( $null, $id, $key ) {
    if ( '_customer_ip_address' === $key )
        return FALSE;

    return $null;
}
```